# Dynamically managing web.config for authorization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, web-config, authorization

I'm using a CMS (N2) to manage a new website. The CMS includes functionality for uploading files using the filesystem (not binary in DB, which is also possible, but I want to use filesystem). Some of the subfolders in the uploads directory need to be secured. This can be done using `authorization` elements in (a sub) `web.config` as stated [here](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/227107?ProjectName=n2cms).

Users and roles are managed through the admin interface and are managed by my CMS administrator. Some roles are added dynamically based on certain functionality in the website. Therefore I would like to keep my `~/upload/xxx` subfolder security dynamic as well. **What is a good solution for dynamically managing authorization based on web.config?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to specify a `<location path="MyFolder">...</location>` in order to open up a specific folder to anyone.

It is a best practice to put these at the bottom of your web.config file and should give you the flexibility you are looking for.

Here's the MSDN page for the location Element:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

Good luck!

Matti

Comment: Nice, reverse the process... Just lock the main folder using roles, and then allowing a specific folder to be public! Nice, nice, nice

Answer (score 1):

Not to do it. Point.

Make your own data file, and plug in a provider to read this, if you dont have a database, use a database otherwise. YOu don want web.config changes to interfere with development / upload changes. VERY nice anti-pattern.

Comment: I understand, however this is only related to 'sub' web.config files, not the root one... Does this change anything?