# ASP.NET How do you dynamically deny access to Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I recently starting trying to use the ASP.NET 4 Membership and Role providers in my web applications. But I'm having problems implementing a good security methodology.

I understand that using web.config files we can grany or deny access to certain aspx files, but is there any good built in way to deny access to a specified Role on certain circumstances?

For example;

We have a page called "EditUser.aspx".

We have two user types; administrators and a standard users. This page is used to edit both types. However, only administrators should be able to edit other administrators.

What is the best approach to stop an authenticated user without the 'admin' role from being able to edit an administrator via EditUser.aspx?

I'm hoping for something a bit more elegant than the below:

```
if(editUser.IsInRole("admin") && !User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    Respone.Redirect("SomeAccessDeniedPage.aspx");
}
```

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275150/dynamically-managing-web-config-for-authorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275150/dynamically-managing-web-config-for-authorization)

Comment: @Maysam - No that's not a similar question as all. I'm not looking to dynamically add roles. I want to be able to allow access to an ASPX page, and then revoke access during the render if the circumstances require it. Please re-read my question.

Comment: I don't think there is anything magical that ASP.NET can do for you here.  The build in functionality as you stated is to make a determination (via web.config) on whether or not a user can access a page all together.  There is nothing that ASP.NET can do in regard to your business logic having this sort of conditional functionality.  I'm assuming you have a list of users on EditUser.aspx, and when someone selects an admin user you execute the above logic.

Comment: @e36M3 - Yes that is what I was affraid of. I dug around in the role provider myself and couldn't see anything. I thought I would put this out there incase I was missing something obvious. 

Unfortunately I think that the role security is just to simplistic for our needs. The example I gave is a very simple one, our system will have a far more complicated logic.

Comment: Understood, however I'm not sure what at all can be done about this from a "framework" perspective.  There is no conditional allow/deny AFAIK other than "yes you the use are in a role" or "no you are not in a role".  You're talking about business rules here, they can be infinite.

Comment: Ahh well, it was worth asking. Even if .net just exposed a Role.DenyAccess() feature that allowed you to mimic the behaviour .net uses, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is to use the LoginView server control with the RoleGroups element. Maybe bind the admin users in a separate gridview and wrap that in a LoginView set to only display to users in the admin role.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but that isn't the problem. I'm not listing users on this page, but editing one particular user. the user is identified using a key passed in URL route data. I have had to develop my own security to deny access to the page.